# Get Response header from Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I need some help.
I would to get the value of response header for get some error information.

There is the contain of response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Pages, X-Page
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
ErrorMessage: entity.name.error
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 18:00:34 GMT
Connection: close
```

Request header:

```
PUT /api/ComponentType HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 44
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

I would to get the error message.

Actually there is my resource:

```
angular.module('MyAPP')
.factory('ComponentTypeRsc',  function ($resource, AppCST) {
    return $resource(AppCST.API_URL + ':' + AppCST.API_PORT +'/api/ComponentType/:id', {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                return data
            }

        },
        'update': { method:'PUT',
           transformResponse: function(data, headers){
            //MESS WITH THE DATA
            response = {}
            response.data = data;
            response.headers = headers();
            return response;
           },
           inteceptor: {
                responseError : resourceErrorHandler,
                response : resourceErrorHandler
            }
        }
    });

    function resourceErrorHandler(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }


});
```

And my controller:

```
 ComponentTypeRsc.update($scope.componentType, function(res, header) {
            $scope.debugCreateOk=res;
            $scope.componentTypes = ComponentTypeSvc.loadAll();
            $('#saveComponentTypeModal').modal('hide');
            // ajoute au tableau le nouvel élement.
            // componentTypes.push({id: $scope.componentType.name });
            $scope.clear();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('error start');
            $scope.debugCreateError = error;
            console.log('error end');
        });
```

Like you can see the value of $scope.debugCreateError doesn't contain ErrorMessage

How can I perform that ?
Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried to put breakpoint in your tranformresponse function and checked wether it is called?

Comment: Hello Chandermani,
First thanks for response.
With wich plugin i can put breakpoint into javascript code ?

Comment: Developer tools for every browser allows you to put breakpoint. F12 is the universal key to open the developer console.

Comment: Thanks, I feeling so stupid, I use Firebug and I don't know we can set breakpoint!
So I set breakpoint into transformResponse but i does not activate, on execution.
I had console.log(response) into resources but nothing is shown into console.

Comment: Will transformResponse even fire when the server returns a 400?  Also, you've added a `resourceErrorHandler` function, but you haven't wired it up.  You need to add an interceptor, and set up the `responseError` handler.

Comment: For the interceptor its an error of my part, I updated my code. But it's seem the interceptor doesn't work.
So the console.log in transformResponse doesn't work to (it's an error 400)